# How do I wait for Threads to complete execution in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a few calculations that I'm spawning off into new threads then when all these calculations are complete I want to continue my execution.

Here's some mock up code that is similar to what I want to achieve without all the specifics,

```
public void calculation1(){
  Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      /* do calculation */
    };
  };
}

public void calculation2(){
  Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      /* do some other calculation */
    };
  };
}

calculation1();
calculation2();

/* Wait here until calculation1() and calculation2() complete */

/* Continue execution */
```

What's the best way for me to do this??

Comment: I think you should try synchronous execution of your methods.

Comment: Start with the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) (links directly to where it starts to get interesting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the join() method on the Thread class - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29

Something like this:

```
  public Thread calculation1(){
      Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          /* do calculation */
        }
      };
      thread.start();
      return thread;
    }

    public Thread calculation2(){
      Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          /* do some other calculation */
        };
      };

      thread.start();
      return thread;
    }
```

And then use isAlive() and join() to wait for execution to finish

```
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    threads.add(calculation1());
    threads.add(calculation2());

    for(Thread t : threads){
        if(t.isAlive()){
           t.join();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Executor` framework to submit `Future` tasks, which will all return in the same time as the longest single task. In its simplest form, this would work:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Future<Object> future1 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return someValue;
    }
});
Future<Object> future2 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return someOtherValue;
    }
});

Object result1 = future1.get();
Object result2 = future2.get();
```

`Future.get()` is a blocking call, which returns as soon as the `Callable` returns, but returns immediately if the `Callable` has already finished, so you will have both `result1` and `result2` in the time it takes the longest one to run.

Remember to `submit()` them all *before* making the first call to `get()`.

---

Also, if you do use `Threads` directly, don't extend `Thread` (unless you're creating a new kind of `Thread`, which you're not): Instead, pass a `Runnable` to the `Thread` constructor and `start()` the `Thread`.

Comment: Plus one (since I can no longer write that in math, what a stupid change).  If you prefer (I do) you can also collect all your Callables in a List and use `invokeAll()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Following is the sample program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyMaster {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       CountDownLatch waitForSlavesToComplete = new CountDownLatch(2);
       new Thread(new MySlave1(waitForSlavesToComplete)).start();
       new Thread(new MySlave2(waitForSlavesToComplete)).start();

      // Wait for all slave threads to complete
      try {
         waitForSlavesToComplete.await(900, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

   }
}

public class MySlave1 extends Thread {

    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    public MySlave1(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        //Perform slave specific operations

        try {
            this.latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class MySlave2 extends Thread {

    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    public MySlave2(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        //Perform slave specific operations

        try {
            this.latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `join` method on your thread with this call no other thread can execute until this thread completes its execution refer [join method doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()), I have written a sample code, in your case Thread1 can be from calculation1 and Thread2 can be in calculation2 method.

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        System.out.println("thread1 is running from method calculation1");
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };

    thread1.start();
    try
    {
      thread1.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e1)
    {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread thread2 = new Thread()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        System.out.println("thread2 is running from method calculation2");
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };
    thread2.start();
    try
    {
      thread2.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
//now here if you have more threads then that will not start until thread 1 and thread 2 are completed
```