# In java, how can I run something, wait for any child background tasks to finish before moving along?

Tags: java, multithreading

I thought creating the child in a separate method and running the method from the main would keep it from moving along until the method was returned, but what I am experiencing is that in the method, I am trying to create a file and then open the file as read-only (which just opens the file from buffer or as a copy), when that gets returned, it deletes the file (since the file technically is not being used), but I'm getting an error that the file is not found when I try to open it. If I comment out the delete code, it opens fine, but I have a bunch of the files piling up. I'm not fully understanding the Thread class.

```
            Integer intRndm = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()*999999999+1));
            String strFile = "C:\\Temp\\IPAddresses" + intRndm + ".xls";
            fileCreate(strFile);
            File DelFile = new File(strFile);
            Process Wait = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Ping -n 4 localhost");
            Wait.waitFor();
            DelFile.delete();

    private void fileCreate(String strFile){
    try{
        InputStream ExIPs = new FileInputStream("\\\\path\\IPAddresses.xls");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(ExIPs);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row1 = sheet.getRow(1);
        Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(2);
        cell1.setCellValue(intStr); 
        Row row2 = sheet.getRow(2);
        Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(2);
        cell2.setCellValue(strOct);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(strFile);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        ExIPs.close();
        fileOut.close();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\EXCEL.EXE\" /r " + strFile);
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return;
    }
}
```

I originally had everything in the fileCreate method in the portion of the above method.  I was told that putting it in its own method should work, but it has not.  I know an option is to use waitFor() with the excecution of excel, but that would mean that the app user would be unable to use the app until they are done using excel, which I do not want to happen. The spreadsheet created is meant to be used along with the app at times. Also the reason for the random number is just in the case that the file ever does not get deleted there won't be a conflict.

I now did the following using threading:

```
    private void butIPsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try{
            Integer intRndm = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()*999999999+1));
            String strFile = "C:\\Temp\\IPAddresses" + intRndm + ".xls";
            CountDownLatch waitForFiles = new CountDownLatch(1);
            FileCreate Pass1 = new FileCreate(waitForFiles, strFile);
            new Thread(Pass1).start();
            waitForFiles.await();
            File DelFile = new File(strFile);
            DelFile.delete();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}                                      

public class FileCreate extends Thread{
    CountDownLatch latch = null;
    String strFile = null;
    public FileCreate(CountDownLatch latch,String strFile){
        this.latch = latch;
        this.strFile = strFile;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            InputStream ExIPs = new FileInputStream("\\\\path\\IPAddresses.xls");
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(ExIPs);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row1 = sheet.getRow(1);
            Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(2);
            cell1.setCellValue(intStr); 
            Row row2 = sheet.getRow(2);
            Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue(strOct);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(this.strFile);
            wb.write(fileOut);
            ExIPs.close();
            fileOut.close();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\EXCEL.EXE\" /r " + this.strFile);
            this.latch.countDown();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

To make sure variables were passing along fine I added some system.outs for the getCount on the latch, before and after its await() and also another in the run() for strFile, to make sure the was passed on right.  before the await it was 1, after the await it was 0, but the exact same thing happened.

One of the answers here says that it is hard, or i guess not possible, to wait until another application finishes opening, which makes sense, the exec simply opens excel, and well it is doing that right and then continues the thread.  I'll just add a waitFor([3or4], TimeUnit.Seconds) to the process.

Comment: Normally you don't want to wait for a background task to run.  That's why you run it in the background.  If you do *need* to wait, just run it in your own thread, it won't be slower and you'll save the overhead of a separate thread.

Comment: Since I am creating the app for windows, in the meantime I employing a process to execute ping -n 4 local host and the waitFor() method for the object.  Works, but I run the risk that if the task I am waiting to finish takes longer than 3 secs, it will fail and if it takes much less time, say 1 sec, I'll have to wait 2secs for no reason. I'd like to have it wait no longer than it needs to.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Also, are you trying to halt all other threads as soon as one of the threads begins processing the file?

Comment: You can think of using CountDownLatch, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309876/how-do-i-wait-for-threads-to-complete-execution-in-java/27310040#27310040) SOF example.

Comment: @markspace not sure what you mean? Due to the lack of appropriate APIs, or unable to find any, that allows me to open an excel spreadsheet & edit it while visible to the user, I am creating a separate temp spreadsheet, using the original as a template.This one has the data I need it to have, I open it with excel as read only & delete the temp file I created. What is happening is that the .exec() to open the xls with excel is right before the delete method I use to delete the file. It starts to open it and it does not wait for that to finish opening, before deleting the file, so it is not found

Comment: Use `Process.waitFor()` to wait for Excel to close.  There's no easy way to wait for a process to 'finish opening' but not close, because it's hard to define when it's finished opening -- see the Win32 function `WaitForInputIdle` and The Old New Thing post on it.

Comment: @user3377627  just curious...if you are opening a read only file for the user ..any reason why you are opening a new temp file for every user..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the DelFile.delete() will be executed before Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE\" /r " + strFile) finish. So you should wait excel process finish and go to delete file
But you still want to use the app when excel file is opening, so you can start process excel in new thread and add waitfor in excel process

new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
            @Override
            public void run() {
             fileCreate(strFile);
             File DelFile = new File(strFile);
             DelFile.delete;
            }
        }).start();

private void fileCreate(String strFile) {
        try {
            InputStream ExIPs = new FileInputStream("\\\\path\\IPAddresses.xls");
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(ExIPs);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row1 = sheet.getRow(1);
            Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(2);
            cell1.setCellValue(intStr);
            Row row2 = sheet.getRow(2);
            Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue(strOct);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(strFile);
            wb.write(fileOut);
            ExIPs.close();
            fileOut.close();
            Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\EXCEL.EXE\" /r " + strFile);
            exec.waitFor();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

usually when you wait for something and then want to be notified ...  you use the observer pattern...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern